# GO solution to structure aliasing?

Tags: go

So I'm trying to port a package from "C" that implements AVL trees. It's an embedded implementation, so the AVL structure is embedded in the structure the application defines.

All of the internal code in the AVL package uses type casting, so if, for example, you put the AVL header at the beginning of your structure, what you pass to the AVL routine is something like

`(struct avl *)&foo`

where foo is your application structure.

As I understand it, GO won't let you do this (not without awful perversions which, as I understand it, are not supported, nor safe.)

That said, here's what I came up with: I added a field to the AVL structure as

`owner interface{}`

I then added a parameter to avl_tree_insert() as

`owner interface{}`

That parameter is a pointer to the beginning of the application structure, so something like this is done:

`avl_tree_insert(root, &mystruct.avl, &mystruct, cmp_func)`

avl_tree_insert then stores the owner interface in the corresponding field in its structure. Routines that look up or traverse the tree return, as before, an AVL node pointer, and the client then does

`nodep = avlp.owner.(*mystruct)`

and is good to go. This all works, but I can't help but wonder if there is a better way? Thanks!

Comment: Just for clarification, you can "type cast" in Go in the same way you would in C, and it's supported, and it's just as safe as in C; which means it's not really safe at all, which is why it's not recommended. "Type assertions" like you're using here accomplish mostly the same thing, yet are still memory-safe.

Comment: I read scary things about GC possibly moving storage, so it's not safe to play casting games.  Possibly I misunderstood.

Comment: GO does not currently have a moving GC, but even if it did, `unsafe.Pointer` is still a pointer to memory and it would still need to be updated like any other pointer. If you were to store the pointer value in something that wasn't a pointer, then sure it could be moved out from underneath you, but don't do that.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense, thanks.  I think I was conflating 2 different issues.  The package I ported from stole the 2 lowest bits in the parent pointer to store a small integer.  To do the same manipulations the "C" code does, I would have had to do games with uintptr, or'ing in the 2 bits, and converting back, which was what I was warned not to do (including by 'go vet').

Comment: You definitely don't want to fiddle with the low bits of pointers, since Go itself might be fiddling with the low bits of pointers. (Various GC algorithms use tricks like this to mark generation numbers, or colorings, for instance.  Go's GC has evolved over the years, and I have no idea what tricks they're using today or will be using tomorrow; I'm just saying that these are common tricks in historical GC implementations.)

Answer (score 2):

A better way would be to use interfaces:

```
type AVLTreeNode interface {
  // functions related to tree links, etc
}

type nodeImpl struct {
  // Implements AVLTreeNode
}

// myNode embeds nodeimpl, so it is an AVLTreeNode
type myNode struct {
   nodeImpl
  // otherFields
}
```

This allows you to write tree management functions using AVLTreeNode interface, and then you can use type assertions to access the concrete structure itself.

```
avl_tree_insert(root, &mystruct, cmp_func)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the kind of input I was hoping for.  I'll take a look at that!

Comment: My intent was to have the AVL package be a standalone entity.  So someone could download it, put 'import "avl"' in their application, and be off and running.  Given that, the AVL package has no way of knowing what structure its node structure is embedded in, without what I did (unless I am missing something?)

Comment: You can still do an interface-base avl package and have other packages implement node interface. You can also do something similar to `container/list` where avl package deals with the tree with an interface{} for the payload. The ideal solution would be to use generics, when they are available.

Comment: Something to look into.  Thanks again!